# Require controller in directive when terminal is true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't load controller's parent in a directive. I have two directives: h-menu and h-menu-item. h-menu uses a controller, and h-menu-item requires that controller.

But h-menu directive has terminal = true, and with this I can't load controller. When I set terminal to false, I can load the controller.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gspVe/4/

html:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <h-menu>
        <h-menu-item>
        </h-menu-item>
    </h-menu>
</div>
```

Here is the code js:

```
angular.module("test", [])

.controller("hMenu", function () {
    this.msg = "controller was loaded";
    return this;
})

.directive("hMenu", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        // comment this and controller will be loaded
        terminal: true, 
        controller: "hMenu",
        require: "hMenu",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var ul = $("<ul/>");
            ul.append(element.children());
            $compile(ul)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(ul);
        }
    };
})

.directive("hMenuItem", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        terminal: true,
        require: "?^hMenu",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var li = $("<li/>");
            if (controller)
                li.html(controller.msg);
            else
                li.html("contoller not loaded!");
            $compile(li)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(li);
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Is it totally necessary to share the controller in this way, can't you rely on scope inheritance like this - http://jsfiddle.net/gspVe/5/

Comment: Why do they need to be terminal? It only matters when you have multiple directives on the same element. Does not look like that's how you are using them.

Comment: Thanks by your idea @Neil, but I can't do that because I need to get the controller for this directive. This controller has some functions that I will call from another scopes.

Comment: From what I could see, this seems to be working by design, as @aet mentioned I don't think you need to use terminal here.  For more information as to why I think it's working as designed, [look at this bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6863#issuecomment-38726523)

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to understand what you're trying to do.  If you want to replace HTML elements, why not use some of the facilities that a directive provides already?

For instance, it looks like you're trying to replace the directive elements with `<ul>` and `<li>`. Rather than define this as you've indicated, why couldn't you do the following:

```
angular.module("test", [])

.directive("hMenu", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E", 
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        template : "<ul ng-transclude></ul>"
    };
})

.directive("hMenuItem", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        template : '<li ng-transclude></li>'
    };
})
```

Then, you can use the power of Angular to indicate menu items declaratively, for example:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <h-menu ng-init="menuitems=['Menu #1', 'Menu #2', 'Menu #3']">
        <h-menu-item ng-repeat="m in menuitems">
            {{m}}
        </h-menu-item>
    </h-menu>
</div>
```

This would show:

- Menu #1
- Menu #2
- Menu #3

I've updated a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/gspVe/9/

Comment: Hi @rchawdry, thanks for your suggestion. I know that I can do it, but in my case, I can't because h-menu have some particularities that are a little bit difficult do explain.

But after try to do with terminal without success, I did it like your idea, but I was need to abandon some of these particularities.

Cheers!